# globbing and $#

Tags: shell-script, wildcards, arguments

Suppose my shell script gets 3 arguments:

```
./myscript dir1 material dir2
```

I need `$#` to report the count of items globbed with `dir1/*` and not the count of my script's original 3 arguments.

Do you know any way I might apply this code?

Comment: Is the shell script's arguments "dir1 material dir2" or "dir1/* material dir2" ?

Comment: @JeffSchaller - though I have edited it since, I made no changes to the asker's invocation commannd line. clearly the arguments are `dir1 material dir2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for  arg
do   set -- "$arg/"*
     [ -e "$1" ]  &&
     printf '%s/*:\t%d\n'  "$arg" "$#"
done
```

if you should like to keep your original args following the execution of such a loop:

```
argc=$#
for  arg
do   set -- "$arg/"* "$@"
     [ -e "$1" ]  &&
     printf '%s/*:\t%d\n' "$arg" "$((${#}-argc))"
     shift "$((${#}-argc))"
done
```